# How can I calculate the orbit of a group action of a group generated by one element?

Tags: group-theory, permutations, group-actions, bit-strings, orbit-stabilizer

I have a bit string, $X$, of $n$ bits. I am applying an operation, $g$, which involves a permutation of the bits and then flipping the first $k$ bits.

I have a proof that the $g$ generates a group because
$$g(gX)=ggX$$
and
$$g^rX=X$$
where $r$ is the order of a permutation applied to an enlarged representation, $Y$, of $X$.  Where $Y$ is of length $2n$ and $Y[2i-1] =  X[i]$ and $Y[2i] = \lnot X[i]$. This results in changing all the bit flips to permutations.

However, $r$ is in general much larger than the orbit of $X$ under $g$.

Are there any techniques to find the size of this orbit other than computing them all?

Can I decompose g into a composition of a permutation followed by another group operation and use that to find the orbit?